# Check if Word Document is Read Only from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I'm trying to detect if a "Microsoft Word Document" has been configured "Read-Only" by MSOffice.

Everything I have read relates to checking using `Get-ItemProperty "C:\tmp\readonly.docx" | Select-Object IsReadOnly`, but that is checking if the File is "read only" from the filesystem level.

The Problem is Microsoft doesn't mark it on the outside, you'd need to open/check with the Microsoft COM object I figure to query if document is read only.

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> Get-ItemProperty "C:\tmp\readonly.docx" | Select-Object IsReadOnly


IsReadOnly
----------
     False
```

Update: If file is configured `RO` without a `Password` then you can simple open as `RW` without a prompt (via powershell), but if it is with a `Password` then you get the prompt to acknowledge `RO` status which is what I want to avoid because it's hanging my script.

Comment: What do you mean by readonly? The NTFS attribute that is checked or that if the file already is open in a Word process?

Comment: @vonPryz Neither. Simply if it's been configured RO by MSOffice Word.

Comment: @slightly snarky all of that is possible, interested to know answers even if they are limited based on that criteria tho!

Comment: There is a difference between ReadOnly and file Level setting, vs if the file is locked. What is the use case for checking for RO vs In Use? Both prevent you from making changes to the doc, but not opening them. If the file system attribute is OS RO set, then you must use the filesystem to remove that attribute. If it is locked, because of in use, you can close that, yet, doing so will lose any unsaved changes. THus doing that randomly is noit prudent.

Comment: My point is you don't need COM to check if a Word doc is RO or not. You just need to check its attributes. That is all Get-ItemProperty is doing. Now if you mean a doc creator set the document as 'Always open as Read Only' in the document protection options, then sure that is different. The OP did not ask about Document Protection in the post at all. Anything done inside Word, then yes you need to use COM/DOM to get at it.

Comment: Good to know... and your final snippet provides more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to test this, I had 3 files as follows:

- A) One regular `test.docx` with no restrictions
- B) One `readonly.docx` w/ a password. This is the file that hung me up w/ a prompt
- C) One `nopass.docx` w/ a read-only setting, but no PWD configured.

A and C would open regardless of the `ReadOnly` setting, but B would hang on a prompt even with `DisplayAlerts` set to `0`. You also couldn't check the `ReadOnly` property unless the prompt was surpassed, or if you set it to `TRUE` it was always true obviosuly.

There is no way I found to check the `ReadOnly` or `HasPassword` property without first openeing document. You can likely inspect the XML file for HEX but I'd say that is less reliable. My way just took some testing/trickery to get working. The important part was I had to pass a password and catch if it failed. Doc's `A/C` would open fine even when you pass a password argument, so no harm there. In the catch I set `ReadOnly = TRUE` and `Visible = TRUE`. You may not need to set the visible part true, but if `ReadOnly = TRUE` then you can't make certain adjustments via `VB` (like `ORIENTATION`) and I'll be using `SENDKEYS` so I'll need the UI if `ReadOnly = TRUE`. As well, hiding the UI is just a "bonus" but not needed. I may just set it always visible if I continue wasting time on coding `IF/THEN` for the `OPENUI` statments.

Anyway... Here is a final code snippet to test on the three files which should result in each file opening w/o a prompt.

```
 #Constants
 Clear-Variable ReadOnly
 $missing = [System.Type]::Missing
 $str = ''
 $PASSWD = 'IsPWDProtected?'
 $wdAlertsNone = 0
 $FILENAME = "C:\tmp\readonly.docx"
 $OPENUI = "TRUE"

 #Start Word
 $ObjWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
 IF ($OPENUI -eq "FALSE"){$ObjWord.Visible  = $FALSE}ELSE{$ObjWord.Visible  = $TRUE}
 $ObjWord.Application.DisplayAlerts = $wdAlertsNone

 #.Open
 IF (!$ConfirmConversions){$ConfirmConversions = $missing}
 IF (!$ReadOnly){$ReadOnly = $FALSE}
 IF (!$AddToRecentFiles){$AddToRecentFiles = $missing}
 IF (!$PasswordDocument){$PasswordDocument = $PASSWD}
 IF (!$PasswordTemplate){$PasswordTemplate = $PASSWD}
 IF (!$Revert){$Revert = $False} 
 IF (!$WritePasswordDocument){$WritePasswordDocument =  $PASSWD}
 IF (!$WritePasswordTemplate){$WritePasswordTemplate =  $PASSWD} 
 IF (!$Format){$Format = 'wdOpenFormatAuto'} 
 IF (!$Encoding){$Encoding = $missing}
 IF (!$Visible){$Visible = $False} 
 try{$ObjDoc=$ObjWord.documents.open($FILENAME,$ConfirmConversions,$ReadOnly,$AddToRecentFiles,$PasswordDocument,$PasswordTemplate,$Revert,$WritePasswordDocument,$WritePasswordTemplate,$Format,$Encoding,$Visible)}
  catch {
     Write-Error  $_
     Write-Host "Opening Read_Only"
     $ReadOnly = $TRUE
     $Visible = $TRUE
     $ObjDoc=$ObjWord.documents.open($FILENAME,$ConfirmConversions,$ReadOnly,$AddToRecentFiles,$PasswordDocument,$PasswordTemplate,$Revert,$WritePasswordDocument,$WritePasswordTemplate,$Format,$Encoding,$Visible)
 }

#AllDone?
PAUSE
$ObjWord.ActiveDocument.Close(0)
$ObjWord.Quit()
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
sleep 2
```

Result:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> C:\tmp\test.ps1
C:\tmp\test.ps1 : The password is incorrect. Word cannot open the document. (C:\tmp\readonly.doc)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test.ps1
 
Opening Read_Only
Press Enter to continue...:
```

Note: I hardcoded `OPENUI = TRUE` during testing because if it got hung on a prompt with the UI closed, I had to use `tskill winword.exe` and start over.

Comment: Glad you have it.

Comment: Further testing shows this is somehow also related to the `VISIBLE` setting. If false, then it opened without prompt via PS. I'm a bit hazy, but regardless, if it fails, this will "catch it" and set all the trouble/visible variables true.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment and note, not using anything dealing with the Word DOM via COM.

```
$File = 'd:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx'

# File not in use
Set-ItemProperty -Path $File  -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
(Get-ItemProperty 'd:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx').IsReadOnly
$File | 
ForEach{
    try   
    {
        $TargetFile = (New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $PSitem).Open(
                                            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, 
                                            [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, 
                                            [System.IO.FileShare]::None
                      )
        $TargetFile.Close()  
        Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -WhatIf  
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
    catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}
# Results
<#
False
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx".
#>

# File in use
Set-ItemProperty -Path $File  -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
(Get-ItemProperty 'd:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx').IsReadOnly
$File | 
ForEach{
    try   
    {
        $TargetFile = (New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $PSitem).Open(
                                            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, 
                                            [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, 
                                            [System.IO.FileShare]::None
                      )
        $TargetFile.Close()  
        Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -WhatIf  
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
    catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}
# Results
<#
False
Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 'd:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx' because it is being used by another process."
#>


# Change the file attribute
# File not in use
Set-ItemProperty -Path $File  -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
(Get-ItemProperty 'd:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx').IsReadOnly
$File | 
ForEach{
    try   
    {
        $TargetFile = (New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $PSitem).Open(
                                            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, 
                                            [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, 
                                            [System.IO.FileShare]::None
                      )
        $TargetFile.Close()  
        Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -WhatIf  
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
    catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}
# Results
<#
True
Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Access to the path 'd:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx' is denied."
#>

# File in use
Set-ItemProperty -Path $File  -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
(Get-ItemProperty 'd:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx').IsReadOnly
$File | 
ForEach{
    try   
    {
        $TargetFile = (New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $PSitem).Open(
                                            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, 
                                            [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, 
                                            [System.IO.FileShare]::None
                      )
        $TargetFile.Close()  
        Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -WhatIf  
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
    catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}
# Results
<#
True
Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Access to the path 'd:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx' is denied."
#>
```

When using Word document protection

```
# with Word doc protection off
#>
$Word = New-Object –comobject Word.Application
Try
{
    ($Word.documents.open($File,$false,$false)).ReadOnly
    Write-Warning -Message "$File is protected ReadOnly"
}
Catch {Write-Verbose -Message "$File is not protected" -Verbose}

# then don't forget to close
$Word.Quit()
# Results 
<#
VERBOSE: d:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx is not protected
#>




# With Word doc protection on
$Word = New-Object –comobject Word.Application
Try
{
    ($Word.documents.open($File,$false,$false)).ReadOnly
    Write-Warning -Message "$File is protected ReadOnly"
}
Catch {Write-Verbose -Message "$File is not protected ReadOnly" -Verbose}

# then don't forget to close
$Word.Quit()
# Results 
<#
True
WARNING: d:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx is protected ReadOnly
#>
```

By accident or on purpose, you could have both set in an environment. I've had this happen to me in auto-classification scenarios. Meaning when FSRM/RMS/AIP has been deployed/implemented and enforced.

***Update***

Here a sample of what I have in my workflow to catch this sort of stuff, as per our exchange.

```
Clear-Host
$Files | 
ForEach{
    $File = $PSItem
    "Processing $PSItem"
    try   
    {
        Write-Verbose -Message 'Word properties:
        DocID, FullName, HasPassword, 
        Permission, ReadOnly, Saved, 
        Creator, CurrentRsid, CompatibilityMode' -Verbose

        'DocID', 'FullName', 'HasPassword', 
        'Permission', 'ReadOnly', 'Saved', 
        'Creator', 'CurrentRsid', 'CompatibilityMode' | 
        ForEach {($Word.documents.open($File,$false,$false)).$PSitem}

        Write-Verbose -Message 'File system ReadOnly attribute:' -Verbose
        (Get-ItemProperty $File).IsReadOnly

        Write-Verbose -Message 'Document state' -Verbose
        $TargetFile = (New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $PSitem).Open(
                                            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, 
                                            [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, 
                                            [System.IO.FileShare]::None
                        )
        $TargetFile.Close()  
        Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -WhatIf  
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
    catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}
# Results
<#
Processing d:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx
VERBOSE: Word properties:
        DocID, FullName, HasPassword, 
        Permission, ReadOnly, Saved, 
        Creator, CurrentRsid, CompatibilityMode
938207550
D:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx
False
True
True
1297307460
12414886
15
VERBOSE: File system ReadOnly attribute:
False
VERBOSE: Document state
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Temp\HSGCopy.docx".
#>
```

Comment: Epic +1 for taking the challenge, I forget why but I have insp3vted the docx XML before, knew there would be a way to tell without the COM/opening doc

Comment: No worries. Document users, owners and policy enforcement has bitten me in the backside way too many times. All environments I've worked and still work in, I make sure watchers are in place for attribute changes and the like. Data custodians often have no clue what state the data is in, then I get a call an say why is X or Y the way it is. It's high tech babysitting. My code just loops thru properties at both levels file system and DOM/COM just because. See my update for what I execute on alerts, or questions from such folks.